# Date type is saved as long type when pyspark write data to elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

nice to meet you.

Nowadays i use Elasticsearch for Apache Hadoop to join elasticsearch index.
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html)

However, i have a problem when pyspark writes data with date type field to elasticsearch.

- Original Field:
- created: timestamp (nullable = true)

However, when i save the data to elasticsearch like below:

```
result.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
.option("es.nodes","server")\
.option("es.mapping.date.rich", "true")\
.option("timestampFormat", "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.sss")\
.option("es.mapping.id","id")\
.mode("append")\
.option("es.resource", "index").save()
```

Fields with date type converted to long type with Unixtimestamp.

However, i want to save the data as date type( like ISO 8601 Format)

How can I save the type as it is?

Please help me

The code i used.

```
# Import PySpark modules
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext

# Spark Config
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("es_app")
conf.set("es.scroll.size", "1000")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

# sqlContext 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Load data from elasticsearch
df = sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.option("es.nodes","server")\
.option("es.nodes.discovery", "true")\
.option("es.mapping.date.rich", 'false')\
.load("index")


# Make view 
df.registerTempTable("test")


all_data = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from test")

result.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")\
.option("es.nodes","server")\
.option("es.mapping.date.rich", "true")\
.option("timestampFormat", "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.sss")\
.option("es.mapping.id","id")\
.mode("append")\
.option("es.resource", "index").save()
```

How can i fixed the problem?

Comment: dates are internally stored as long only, so I guess there is no issue here, can you explain in more details your issue and see the answer written by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please define mapping for your date field and use `Date` field of Elasticsearch which supports multiple date formats. also `date` fields in Elasticsearch is internally stored as long.

Ref :- [date datatype in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html)

[Define date field in mapping with various formats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#mapping-date-format)

Also please read this note about how date fields are internally stored and displayed

```
Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified)
and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch.

Dates will always be rendered as strings, even if they were initially
supplied as a long in the JSON document.
```

### Example

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So if i want to the field as ISO 8601 (2017-04-22T06:33:32.000Z), do i have to convert the field type to string?

Comment: @sunlim no you just need to define it to date type and by default it stores the date in UTC format which is ISO 8601, please refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#:~:text=JSON%20doesn't%20have%20a,%2Dsince%2Dthe%2Depoch and https://www.elastic.co/blog/converting-local-time-to-iso-8601-time-in-elasticsearch which will be useful